# python+django-unchecked checkbox returns "none"

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have an HTML form with checkbox:

```
<form action="...function x" method="POST">

{% for x in box %}

<tr class="cart_row_{{forloop.counter0}}"name="cart_row_{{forloop.counter0}}">
<td>

 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"value="-1" checked="0" name="check_{{forloop.counter0}}">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="check_{{forloop.counter0}}">Select item</label>

 </td>

</tr>

{% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="Checkout">

</form>
```

When the checkbox is checked, everything works fine.
When the checkbox isn't checked, django returns this error:

```
TypeError at ...:'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The cause of the error is that the checkbox value is "none".

How can I get over this?

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes does not appear in POST data if it is not checked. So you should check like this in your view.

```py
if 'checkbox_input_name' in request.POST:
  checked = True
```

Comment: ```checked = request.POST.get('checkbox_input_name', False)```

Or maybe this would be more suitable ?

Comment: Welcome to SOF Laury.I found the solution by: 
```if request.POST.get(checkbox_name) is not None
```. That made me get around the exception that froze the code. I appreciated your helpful post :)